# Do hotel pre-open bananas to prevent clients from taking them for after breakfast?

Tags: food-and-drink, hotels, factoids

I have seen this a few times in breakfast buffets in hotels: pre-opened bananas (e.g. see infra).

Is that done in order to prevent clients from taking them for after breakfast, since an opened bananas will not last long?

[image]

Comment: I haven't seen it. But probably yes.

Comment: Maybe, they are helping clients by opening it for them.

Comment: It's posh, a little extra TLC for the customer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about food, not about travel

Comment: @Willeke well it is about hotels.

Comment: Close?  it's couldn't be more clearly about hotel procedures -- it's a great, if fun, question for the site!

Comment: I doubt that's the reasoning. Probably just for uniformity & presentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No**, it's simply done to make it more convenient, more "elegant" if you will.

Just as they might, say, pull the stems from apples or polish apples.

Some joints actually start to pull the banana skin down for you, to make it even easier!  :)

Comment: I had no idea peeling a banana required so much effort :)

Comment: @Blackbird57 If you peel the banana from the bottom it is much easier ;)